# Double Organize not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have a script:

```
Sub wsPOT()
    Dim wsPOT As Worksheet
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long, lastrow2 As Long, fstcell As Long, i As Long, Er As Long, lstCol As Long, lstRow As Long

    Set wsPOT = Sheets("PO Tracking")

    With wsPOT
        wsPOT.Range("Q1:U1").Copy
        lastrow = wsPOT.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            wsPOT.Range("V1:X1").Copy wsPOT.Range("H3:J" & lastrow)
            wsPOT.Range("N2:O2").Copy wsPOT.Range("N3:O" & lastrow)
            wsPOT.Range("P1:V1").Copy
            wsPOT.Range("B3:H" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            wsPOT.Range("K3:K" & lastrow).Borders.Weight = xlThin


        lastrow = wsPOT.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            wsPOT.Range("H:J").Calculate
            wsPOT.Range("B3:K" & lastrow).Sort key1:=Range("H3:H" & lastrow), order1:=xlAscending
        lastrow2 = wsPOT.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
            wsPOT.Range("B3:K" & lastrow2).Sort key1:=Range("H3:H" & lastrow2), order1:=xlDescending
    End With

End Sub
```

This is meant to ultimately organize the sheet so that the the late jobs are on top, and then those are organized by oldest to youngest.

It seems not to work. What seems to happen is that the first orginization works fine, but then it seems to ignore the second criteria.

Attached is the sheet, with script.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/Orga.xlsm

If someone can help look at this it be apprecaited.

Comment: besides others answer below why do you have `lastrow` and `lastrow2` when both are set to this statement `wsPOT.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row` and you have nothing in between them that adds rows to column H??? And since I am commenting (and others have adjusted this for)... when you use `With` statements you don't need to reference your object each time within them. In fact, doing so actually *negates* the purpose of the 'With` statements! It slows down your code and makes it harder to read. See below answers to understand better.

Comment: Ok I got the 2nd link. Let me have a loot at it.

Comment: Is this what you are trying? http://wikisend.com/download/381778/Untitled.png

Comment: @ScottHoltzman the reason for the two, which BTW I corrected the script above a little, the original is meant to select all of the sheet, and organize H by dates, so in this case the youngest is up top, the oldest is towards the bottom. The second is so that it should take only the ones with data in H to organize it so that the oldest it first and the youngest in on the bottom.  Which is not happening.

Comment: @SiddharthRout close, except reverse it, the oldest on the top...I can get there no problem, it's the reversing of it I can't figure out.  What I have written up should work in theory...

Comment: 'PO Data' sheet is not in workbook. Can't test without it.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman yes you can, the information that is required is there, the only reason for the PO Data is to get another number all together... which is not part of this formula.

Comment: @SiddharthRout yes, red on top, with the largest number first, then lowest number, and under that green.

Comment: I have posted the answer. See if that is what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub wsPOT()
    Dim wsPOT As Worksheet
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long, lastrow2 As Long, fstcell As Long
    Dim i As Long, Er As Long, lstCol As Long, lstRow As Long

    Set wsPOT = Sheets("PO Tracking")

    With wsPOT
        .Range("Q1:U1").Copy
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("V1:X1").Copy .Range("H3:J" & lastrow)
        .Range("N2:O2").Copy .Range("N3:O" & lastrow)
        .Range("P1:V1").Copy
        .Range("B3:H" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        .Range("K3:K" & lastrow).Borders.Weight = xlThin
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("H:J").Calculate

        .Sort.SortFields.Clear

        '~~> Sort on Red Icon First, putting it on top
        .Sort.SortFields.Add(.Range("J3:J" & lastrow), _
        xlSortOnIcon, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SetIcon Icon:=ActiveWorkbook. _
        IconSets(4).Item(1)

        '~~> Sort on Values of Red icon in descending order
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "J3:J" & lastrow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal

        '~~> Sort on Green Icon Next, putting it on top after Red
        .Sort.SortFields.Add(.Range("I3:I" & lastrow), _
        xlSortOnIcon, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SetIcon Icon:=ActiveWorkbook. _
        IconSets(4).Item(3)

        '~~> Sort on Values of Green icon next in descending order
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "I3:I" & lastrow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal

        With .Sort
            .SetRange wsPOT.Range("B2:K" & lastrow)
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `Jobs List` which the formula `V1` is referring to?

Comment: That is a hidden tab in the worksheet... as for your post, `SortOn:=xlSortOnValues` I am getting an error on the SortOn, says `Named Argument not found`

Comment: Did you copy it correctly? I tested it and it give me this image http://wikisend.com/download/864736/Untitled.png

Comment: I do have a question the `With .Sort` I've never seen this used like that, what is the definition of it's function? In other words, what is this function called so i can look it up and use it for other stuff?

Comment: .Sort has evolved over Excel versions. Excel 2003 had it very simple but it became slightly complex after Excel 2007. I still use the 2003 version :) Maybe that it because I hardly work with icons. I would recommend checking Excel's inbuilt help on how Sorting works. Also would recommend recording macros to see how the code is generated for different sort functions.

Comment: I only use icons for the end user, otherwise I'd agree. I was thinking about the recording macros, but it pushes a lot of data out that I honestly don't know if I need. Sometimes it is better to ask and get the correct answer, than guessing and blowing everything up by accident. Thanks again :)

Comment: I can understand your point. But I would recommend to do exactly what you are sort of scared of :). What I mean is, create a backup copy of the file and then do all kinds of experiments with it. I believe (and this is just my opinion) that is the best way to learn :)